# Can't figure out how to implement a tuple in a palindrome checker

Tags: python, tuples, palindrome

So I'm learning python from a book, and I'm at the input/output section, in which it gives an example of code that checks for palindromes, but it only works for a word. After that it asks if I can improve the code by having a tuple contain the forbidden characters so that it can check if sentences like "Rise to vote, sir." are palindromes. I've been at it for a couple of time and I just can't wrap my head around how should I implement it.

The example code:

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def is_palindrome(text):
    return text == reverse(text)

something = input("Enter text: ")
if is_palindrome(something):
    print("Yes, it is a palindrome")

else:
    print("No, it is not palindrome")
```

What I've tried to do:

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def sanitize(text):
    text = text.lower
    forbidden = (" ", ".", ",", "!", "?")
    if forbidden in text:
        text.replace(forbidden, "")
    return text

something = input("Enter text: ")

def is_palindrome(text):
    text = sanitize(text)
    return text == reverse(text)

if is_palindrome(something):
    print("Yes, it is a palindrome")

else:
    print("No, it is not palindrome")
```

Of course this is wrong and throws out an error, but I've tried multiple attempts at it and I just can't figure it out, I'm sure the answer is really simple but I can't find

Comment: At `text.lower` you forgot `()`

Comment: After the changes suggested, it throws out an error on the in operand, saying it requires a string not a tuple.

Comment: text.replace does not modify text *in situ* - it returns the modified string. Python strings are immutable. Also, it doesn't make sense to convert just one of the strings being compared to lowercase. You need to convert both of them

Comment: I don't quite understand the second statement, I'm trying to lower case the input then remove the punctuation. Should I convert to lower case in the first function as well?

Comment: Don't convert to lowercase in the sanitize function. Rather: *return text.lower() == reverse(text).lower()*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be more efficient (without using additional modules) to implement *sanitize* like this:

```
def sanitize(text):
  forbidden = (" ", ".", ",", "!", "?")
  tl = []
  for c in text:
    if not c in forbidden:
      tl.append(c)
  return ''.join(tl)
```

Of course, the *forbidden* variable could be a list, tuple or set.

Using a list comprehension is more concise but any difference in performance (either way) is likely to be marginal.

```
def sanitize(text):
  return ''.join([c for c in text if c not in (" ", ".", ",", "!", "?")])
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but I want to ask, what did you do to tl by assigning square brackets, also, how could I take care if the input contains uppercase?

Comment: square brackets are used to denote a Python list. Appending to a list is likely to be faster than reconstructing strings

Answer (score 0):

I found a few problems with your code.

`text.lower`  should be changed to `text.lower()`. you should use a for loop to iterate through `forbidden` . And `text`  should be updated to `text.replace(c, “”)`  and `c`  is each value in `forbidden` . This should be the code

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def sanitize(text):
    text = text.lower()
    forbidden = (" ", ".", ",", "!", "?")
    for c in forbidden:
        text = text.replace(c, "")
    return text

something = raw_input("Enter text: ")

def is_palindrome(text):
    text = sanitize(text)
    return text == reverse(text)

if is_palindrome(something):
    print("Yes, it is a palindrome")

else:
    print("No, it is not palindrome")
```

Comment: This will not work if the input contains mixed case letters